# jquery check/uncheck all by class

Tags: jquery

but honestly it has me stumped. I have looked on the interweb and just can't find a solution that fits my needs

```
<div id="TOP123">Top</div>
<div id="BOT123">Bottom</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#TOP123").on('click',function(){
    $(".TOP123").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
$("#BOT123").click(function() {
    $(".BOT123").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
</script>

<div id="ImageContainer">

<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][0]" value="1" id="CEKPOS1123" class="CEKPOS1 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][1]" value="1" id="CEKPOS2123" class="CEKPOS2 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][2]" value="1" id="CEKPOS3123" class="CEKPOS3 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][3]" value="1" id="CEKPOS4123" class="CEKPOS4 BOT123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][4]" value="1" id="CEKPOS5123" class="CEKPOS5 BOT123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][5]" value="1" id="CEKPOS6123" class="CEKPOS6 BOT123 originalinput" />

</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is the Top Div(Button) check/uncheck all checkboxes by class TOP123.
and same with Bottom div check/uncheck all checkboxes by class BOT123
I have tried a lot of variations and why TOP and BOT functions are different
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$("#TOP123").on('click', function() {
  $(".TOP123").prop('checked', !$(".TOP123").is(":checked"));
});
$("#BOT123").click(function() {
  $(".BOT123").prop('checked', !$(".BOT123").prop("checked"));
});
```

`$(this).prop("checked")` refers to that you are trying to set the "button/div" to checked, but instead use `!$(".TOP123").is(":checked")` it will ask if the `.TOP123` checkbox is checked or not, and reverse it.

**Working demo**

```js
$("#TOP123").on('click', function() {
  $(".TOP123").prop('checked', !$(".TOP123").is(":checked"));
});
$("#BOT123").click(function() {
  $(".BOT123").prop('checked', !$(".BOT123").prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TOP123">Top</div>
<div id="BOT123">Bottom</div>

<div id="ImageContainer">

  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][0]" value="1" id="CEKPOS1123" class="CEKPOS1 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][1]" value="1" id="CEKPOS2123" class="CEKPOS2 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][2]" value="1" id="CEKPOS3123" class="CEKPOS3 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][3]" value="1" id="CEKPOS4123" class="CEKPOS4 BOT123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][4]" value="1" id="CEKPOS5123" class="CEKPOS5 BOT123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][5]" value="1" id="CEKPOS6123" class="CEKPOS6 BOT123 originalinput" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the classes and toggle the  checked state to to each item in that class,

```js
$("#TOP123").on('click',function(){
    $(".TOP123").each(function(){
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
       $(this).prop("checked", !checked)
    });
})


$("#BOT123").on('click',function(){
    $(".BOT123").each(function(){
      var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
       $(this).prop("checked", !checked)
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="TOP123">Top</div>
<div id="BOT123">Bottom</div>

<div id="ImageContainer">

<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][0]" value="1" id="CEKPOS1123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS1 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][1]" value="1" id="CEKPOS2123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS2 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][2]" value="1" id="CEKPOS3123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS3 TOP123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][3]" value="1" id="CEKPOS4123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS4 BOT123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][4]" value="1" id="CEKPOS5123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS5 BOT123 originalinput" />
<input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][5]" value="1" id="CEKPOS6123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS6 BOT123 originalinput" />

</div>
```

Comment: Op says `check/uncheck all checkboxes by class` but with your code you can only check it.

Comment: Also please take your time when you answer, basic this line don't make sense ` tje classaes and pply the checked astate to ech ite`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is:

```
$(this).prop("checked")
```

`$(this)` is referring to the div you clicked on, not the checkboxes.

Instead, you can change this (and the buttom one to ".BOT123") to:

```
!$(".TOP123").prop("checked"));
```

Which will change your checkboxes to the opposite value of what they currently are.

See example below:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="TOP123">Top</div>
<div id="BOT123">Bottom</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#TOP123").on('click', function() {
    $(".TOP123").prop('checked', !$(".TOP123").prop("checked"));
  });
  $("#BOT123").click(function() {
    $(".BOT123").prop('checked', !$(".BOT123").prop("checked"));
  });
</script>

<div id="ImageContainer">

  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][0]" value="1" id="CEKPOS1123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS1 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][1]" value="1" id="CEKPOS2123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS2 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][2]" value="1" id="CEKPOS3123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS3 TOP123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][3]" value="1" id="CEKPOS4123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS4 BOT123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][4]" value="1" id="CEKPOS5123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS5 BOT123 originalinput" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="ImagePositions[123][5]" value="1" id="CEKPOS6123" onchange="Alterticketdata(\'123\')" class="CEKPOS6 BOT123 originalinput" />

</div>
```

**Note:** The determining factor which checks whether to change the checkboxes to check/unchecked is the first checkbox for each group (ie the 1st and 4th checkbox).